# Access Run nested elements - Python Docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

This is the xml extraced from the word document

```xml
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rtl/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
      <w:ffData>
        <w:name w:val="נפתח1"/>
        <w:enabled/>
        <w:calcOnExit w:val="0"/>
        <w:ddList>
          <w:listEntry w:val="A"/>
          <w:listEntry w:val="B"/>
          <w:listEntry w:val="C"/>
          <w:listEntry w:val="D"/>
          <w:listEntry w:val="E"/>
        </w:ddList>
      </w:ffData>
    </w:fldChar>
</w:r>
```

I'm trying to get to the `<w:ddList>` sections, but I cant get past the `<w:r>` section

I know its possible to get the run element the following way

```py
run = doc.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
```

but runs doesn't have any list like attribute, so I'm about clueless how to continue, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `run._r`, which is the `lxml.etree._Element` (subtype) object representing the `<w:r>` element.

From there you can use XPath expressions to get to what you're after, like:

```
r = run._r
fldChars = r.xpath("./w:fldChar")
```

The return value of a `.xpath()` call will be a list of zero or more objects matching the XPath expression.

`python-docx`-implemented element objects, so-called `oxml` objects with type names like `CT_Run`, have a fancier `.xpath()` implementation that delivers you from having to fuss over namespaces.  The `run._r` object is one of these. If you invoke for example `fldChars[0].xpath(...)` (`fldChart` would be a "plain" `lxml.etree._Element` object) then you need to provide Clark-name style namespaces for each element, which is ugly at best.

The `lxml` documentation has more on that, but if you can "root" your XPath search on a `python-docx` element like `run._r` then you can avoid that, using like `r.xpath("./w:fldChar/w:ffData")` to get at those child elements for example, rather than starting at the `w:fldChar` element.